# Debugging resume after prelaunch in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app

My UWP app seems to have trouble waking up when it was prelaunched. The problem is that it's stuck at the ExtendedSplashscreen when prelaunched. I'd like to debug this, but I haven't found any way in Visual Studio to simulate the startup when the app is prelaunched. I've found an option to do the prelaunch itself, but that's not what I want.

Am I stuck with deploying the app in release mode and using logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use "Debug installed app package" option, and disable auto launch.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781607.aspx#BKMK_Start_an_installed_app_in_the_debugger